# Get Object element from a variable

Tags: javascript

I have an object that i am trying to pull values from according to a certain variable.

Let say i have an object

```
current = [
goal1 : solve this,
goal2: sleep,]
```

`current.goal1` returns solve this.
but what if i have a variable called `task` that can be either goal1 or goal2
how can i call `current.goal1` by using `task` variable.

`current.task` returns undefined.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```js
const current = {
goal1 : "solve this",
goal2: "sleep"};

const task = "goal1";

console.log(current[task]);
```

This is known as `Square brackets property access`: **object['property']**

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying current.[task] and it wasnt working. now i can solve this and sleep :) thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. Object syntax: between curly braces {}

```js
let current = {
  task: {
    goal1 : 'solve this',
    goal2: 'sleep'
  }
};

const { task } = current;

console.log(task)
```

By using Destructured assignment

Comment: thx but namar answered what i need by  Square brackets property access: object['property']. Thx for your help